# My theory to travel near the speed of light. Why will this theory not work?

Tags: faster-than-light, rocket-science

Why can't a spacecraft travel near the speed of light? Here's my theory.

We assemble the spacecraft in the Earth's orbit just like the **International Space Station**, each time, equipping it with lots of fuel. And finally, we have created a giant spacecraft orbiting the Earth with lots and lots of fuel. We plot a course which is really long with no obstacles or celestial bodies in between by using our scientific knowledge to check exoplanet's orbits. We then send the space craft having lots of fuel in it. Let's suppose the spacecraft is travelling at **x** kmph now. Since space has no particles to retard the speed, we accelerate more and more till we nearly reach the speed of light. The speed will be maintained throughout the journey, thus helping us to travel in the speed of light.

I am sure this would not actually be possible, but I want to know exactly why.

Comment: With enough fuel, you can come arbitarily close to the speed of light. Why do you think that wouldn't be possible?

Comment: "*...till we nearly reach the speed of light*" is correct, but "*...helping us to travel in the speed of light.*" is not. We **cannot** travel at the speed of light...

Comment: Well we've been told you can't travel faster than light in school. That's why this misconception. We've also been told in space there is nothing to decelerate an object. So I've asked my teacher about it and she said "In theory it may work, but not in practice. We cannot break the luminous barrier". That increased my curiosity and that's exactly why I posted the same here.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Why exactly this cannot happen? If we have enough fuel, we can accelerate more and we can reach the speed of light na?

Comment: @SiddharthVenu are you sure she said that in theory we could break the luminous barrier?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I'm sorry I'm not being brief. I told her about travelling 'near' the speed of light. And why can't we reach the speed of light by accelerating?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN may i recommend you to read about classical mechanics to fully understand *your* mistakes?

Comment: @SiddharthVenu : people are confused because you are telling contradictory elements: sometime you say "very close to light speed", and some other time you say "break the whole of light speed". ( The first is possible IF you have astronomical amount of fuel and time. The second is impossible. )

Comment: @accidentalfouriertransform I meant constant acceleration and not constant velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that classically, a constant force leads to a constant acceleration, due to Newton's second law.  Relativistically, though, it's more correct to use the momentum form of Newton's second law: $$\vec{F} = \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt},$$ with the relativistic momentum defined $$ p = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}.$$

As $v$ gets closer and closer to $c$, each differential bit of momentum does less and less to increase the speed, and in the limit as $v$ goes to $c$, $\frac{dv}{dp}$ goes to zero. In other words, you can push your momentum to infinity by applying force, but that will only take you up to the speed of light, and not past it.

As to why that's the correct form for the relativistic momentum, I'd refer you to an introductory text on Special Relativity. Taylor and Wheeler's *Spacetime Physics* is readable and tries to rely more on physical intuition than on mathematics, so you might start there.